What is the purpose of last_queried_date query parameter in liststatuschanges DocuSign API end-point?

The image indicates that DocuSign's last_queried_date parameter is intended to return envelopes modified before the specified date.
However, despite trying various dates with the 'last_queried_date' along with the from_date parameter and other parameters like order and status, the result set remains unchanged.
I am seeking clarification on the actual purpose of this parameter, as my goal is to reduce the size of the returned envelope results.
Furthermore, it would seem more logical for the parameter to return envelopes modified after the last_queried_date. Currently, it appears that the last_queried_date parameter is not functioning as expected.

are you saying from_date is not working either?

no, from_date is working fine

so, when you use last_queried_date, you get the same result? no matter what date you put?

I just mentioned checking if last_queried_date is working, I tried different from_date and last_queried_date too but the only impact on the result was against from_date

yes, same result
